# change placement of shapes based on screen size in Placement.info file

Tags: orchardcms

I use Orchard CMS 1.10.1. I was wondering is there a way to change placement of shapes based on **screen size** in `Placement.info` file.

For example I don't want to display some shapes on mobile screen size or change the position of some shapes on mobile screen.

What is the best practice for this purpose?

Comment: This sounds more like css's job. I don't think the server will know of the screen size of your window, and the placement.info is executed on the server side

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it with 'placement.info' file, but if you want to render your html based on user agent (PC, IOS, Android .. etc) you can do it by return the right shapes from drivers based on user agent, or if you want to return the same html code and render it differently on the client browser based on screen size then you have to use css to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks guys for answer, I'll handle it with css then